# RadGrid - Multiple Controls in same column in edit template in Batch Edit

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am using batch editing in a radgrid with save button outside the grid. In side grid there are template columns and their edit templates have multiple values. I am able to assign values to them. But when I click on save in side bath edit command method the corresponding key of newvalues gives value of [object object]

```
 <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Dwg Sch" ColumnGroupName="WACompOrderEntry" UniqueName="DwgSchedule" HeaderTooltip="This is the date the factory has promised to provide approval drawings to the field (loaded automatically from Vista when available)">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblRdDwgSch" Text='<%# Eval("Vista_Sub", "{0:M/d/yy}") %>' ToolTip="This is the date the factory has promised to provide approval drawings to the field (loaded automatically from Vista when available)"></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDwgSch" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="rdDwgSch" runat="server" Width="80px" DbSelectedDate='<%# Eval("Vista_Sub", "{0:M/d/yy}") %>' ToolTip="This is the date the factory has promised to provide approval drawings to the field (loaded automatically from Vista when available)"></telerik:RadDatePicker>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDwgSch" runat="server" Width="80px" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Above is the template column definition

```
   protected void gridMilestoneMatrixEntry_BatchEditCommand(object sender, GridBatchEditingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Commands == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            Cache.Remove("MileStoneData");
            var updatedCommands = e.Commands.Where(x => x.Type == GridBatchEditingCommandType.Update);
            var deletedCommands = e.Commands.Where(x => x.Type == GridBatchEditingCommandType.Delete);
            List<int> updatedRecords = new List<int>();
            List<long> deletedRecords = new List<long>();
            if (updatedCommands != null && updatedCommands.Count() > 0)
            {
                updatedRecords = UpdateMilestoneMatrix(updatedCommands.ToList());
            }
```

Now inside the hashtable key values do not give values for object
updatedValues["DwgSchedule"] it gives value as [object object]

```
 if (updatedValues["DwgSchedule"] != null)
                {
                    tempStr = updatedValues["DwgSchedule"].ToString();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tempStr))
                    {
                        confDwgExp = DateTime.ParseExact(updatedValues["DwgSchedule"].ToString(), "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    }
                    tempStr = string.Empty;
                }
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the value / attributes of the object in Visual Studio's "Immidiate window" while debugging?

Comment: yes i tried, its [object, object]

Comment: Regardless of what is happening I think it would be wise to use a different strategy when implementing your batch edit; when you click the save, why not simply iterate through the rows and extract every cell's data and send that data to whatever source you are using?

Answer (score 1):

The way I decided to go about doing these things was to have the iterate through the rows of the grid by using the `RadGrid.Items`
This allows you to access each individual row, which in essence gives you access to the row's individual controls (i.e not just the cells, but everything on the row).

```
Private Sub RbtnSaveAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RbtnSaveAll.Click

    For Each item As GridDataItem In grdActivities.Items 'Iterates over the rows
    'Get your controls by using item.findcontrol("controlname").
    'Then send the data of the changed controls to the datasource
    Next

    bindGrid(True) 'Do your bind event if necessary
End Sub
```

If you want a c# version you can simply convert it using  [telerik's converter](http://converter.telerik.com/)

EDIT:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnBulkBookOn" runat="server" Text="Book On" CommandName="Update"/>
```

VB-code:

```
        Private Sub radgrdResources_UpdateCommand(sender As Object, e As GridCommandEventArgs) Handles radgrdResources.UpdateCommand
' This will be invoked when you clikc the button and fire off the Radgrid's native save.
    End Sub
```

Comment: I am able to find the controls, they are labels as the batch editing is already closed, but their text is empty.

Comment: Could you add an edit with your code? I might be able to give more detailed help, then

Comment: First off it would seem like there is no item with the ID="DwgSchedule" in the code you posted.
Secondly as long as you have a button inside the grid (commandtemplate or whatever?) you cna simply specify the CommandName to be "Update" and Radgrid's native update command will be fired off and update everything accordingly.

Comment: I have updated the code, the key for DwgSch shows [object object]. Also, I am not using save button of grid, calling batch edit save from javascript on click of a button. But I have tried with Save button also, and it also made no difference.